# Nextjs use client cannot access <Component> before initialization

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13, hydration

I have what I consider to be a fairly straightforward use case in Nextjs, that is, a `NavigationBar` component with a search input.

```
<div className="w-full flex flex-row items-center py-5 justify-between">
    <div className="w-40">
      <Link href="/">
        <Image
          className="mx-5"
          src="images/logomark.svg"
          width={100}
          height={32}
          alt={"logo"}
        />
      </Link>
    </div>
    <SearchBar />
</div>
```

However I recently added `use client;` to the top of it in preparation to make it stateful. Immediately it began to throw `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'NavigationBar' before initialization`.

Using the process of elimination I found the culprit to be `<SearchBar />`, which was stateful and had `use client;` in it. If I removed SearchBar, it would render.

I am wondering what within SearchBar was causing this issue, so again I removed everything to try to get it not to error. I removed `use client;`, removed all logic, and replaced the return with a simple `<div />`. It still throws the error.

Updated SearchBar component:

```
export const SearchBar = () => {
  return <div />;
};
```

At this point it is completely unclear to me what could be causing this issue. I assume there is something related to hydration, perhaps HTML semantics, but it is not clear what or how to debug this.

There is also a runtime stack trace:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Cannot access 'NavigationBar' before initialization

Warning: An error occurred during hydration. The server HTML was replaced with client content in <#document>.

The above error occurred in the <NotFoundErrorBoundary> component:

Uncaught Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SearchBar.js

```
'use client'
const SearchBar = () => {
  return (
    <div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchBar;
```

in NavigationBar.js

```
import SearchBar from './SearchBar'
<div className="w-full flex flex-row items-center py-5 justify-between">
    <div className="w-40">
      <Link href="/">
        <Image
          className="mx-5"
          src="images/logomark.svg"
          width={100}
          height={32}
          alt={"logo"}
        />
      </Link>
    </div>
    <SearchBar />
</div>
```

Could you try doing it this way? You seem to have a problem creating and importing. Try "export default SearchBar" and see if your import is correct. I would appreciate it if you let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).